# TensorFlow Error Message: AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists

Tags: tensorflow

This is Jupyter Notebook

I have made sure that I am not trying to import it twice. I have tried a few other things as well but, I am not sure why I am getting this error. Here is the code:

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

train_x.shape

model = keras.models.Sequential()

model = add(keras.layers.Input(Shape=13))
model = add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation= 'relu'))
model = add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation= 'relu'))
model = add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation= 'relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

### Which then I get the following error from what I get out of this is that there is an issue with importing it more then once but, I am not doing that:

```
AlreadyExistsError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-dc91f937e913> in <module>
----> 1 model = keras.models.Sequential()
  2 
  3 model = add(keras.layers.Input(Shape=13))
  4 model = add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation= 'relu'))
  5 model = add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation= 'relu'))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from keras import models
     26 
     27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in <module>
     18 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from keras import optimizer_v1
     22 from keras.engine import functional

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py in <module>
     24 
     25 import numpy as np
---> 26 from keras import activations
     27 from keras import backend
     28 from keras.engine import base_layer

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras.layers import advanced_activations
     21 from keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
     22 from keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 # Generic layers.
---> 23 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     24 from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
     25 from keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in <module>
     19 from keras import backend
     20 from keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
---> 21 from keras.engine import base_layer
     22 from keras.engine import keras_tensor
     23 from keras.engine import node as node_module

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in <module>
     41 from keras.engine import node as node_module
     42 from keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 43 from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     44 from keras.mixed_precision import policy
     45 from keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\mixed_precision\loss_scale_optimizer.py in <module>
     16 
     17 from keras import backend
---> 18 from keras import optimizers
     19 from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale as keras_loss_scale_module
     20 from keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in <module>
     24 from keras.optimizer_v1 import Optimizer
     25 from keras.optimizer_v1 import TFOptimizer
---> 26 from keras.optimizer_v2 import adadelta as adadelta_v2
     27 from keras.optimizer_v2 import adagrad as adagrad_v2
     28 from keras.optimizer_v2 import adam as adam_v2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\adadelta.py in <module>
     20 import numpy as np
     21 from keras import backend_config
---> 22 from keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
     23 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
     24 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py in <module>
     34 
     35 
---> 36 keras_optimizers_gauge = tf.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
     37     "/tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers", "keras optimizer usage", "method")
     38 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py in __init__(self, name, description, *labels)
    358       *labels: The label list of the new metric.
    359     """
--> 360     super(BoolGauge, self).__init__('BoolGauge', _bool_gauge_methods,
    361                                     len(labels), name, description, *labels)
    362 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py in __init__(self, metric_name, metric_methods, label_length, *args)
    133           self._metric_name, len(self._metric_methods)))
    134 
--> 135     self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
    136 
    137   def __del__(self):

AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no details, only link - don't post content that depends on links, instead copy relevant parts of content into here.

Comment: I just updated it - I am new and normally work with screenshots so maybe give the comment and then give the user a chance to update you can clearly see when someone is new.

Comment: You have a chance to fix after vote.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using is `keras` not `tensorflow.keras` therefore you need:

```
import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer='adam', metrics=[...])
history = model.fit(
    numpy.array(train_x),
    numpy.array(train_y),
    epochs=...,
    verbose=True,
    validation_data=(numpy.array(valid_x), numpy.array(valid_y)),
)
```

**Note that this is `model.add()`, not `add()`**

If you want to do `import tensroflow` then you are using a different API and your code will need to look different.